# TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, pandas

I am really a beginner in Python
I'm working on a projekt, which i have to extract all elements of the building.
for that i wrote the code:

```
import ifcopenshell.geom
import ifcopenshell.util
from ifcopenshell.util.selector import Selector
selector = Selector()
import ifcopenshell.util.element as util
import pandas as pd
import ifcopenshell
ifc = ifcopenshell.open('FHZGR_PONTE DELL`ACCADEMIA_PH01_BEM.ifc')
ifc
```

and then:

```
elements = selector.parse(ifc, '.IfcWall | .IfcSlab | .IfcWindow | .IfcDoor | .IfcRamp | .IfcColumn | .IfcBeam | .IfcStair')
elements
```

afterwards:

```
l = []
for element in elements:
    l.append(elements, columns = ['Klasse', 'Typ', 'Objekt', 'ID'])
l
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df
```

But the last code lines returns me:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [17], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 l = []
      2 for element in elements:
----> 3     l.append(elements, columns = ['Klasse', 'Typ', 'Objekt', 'ID'])
      4 l
      5 df = pd.DataFrame(l)

TypeError: append() takes no keyword arguments
```

Can someone please help to solve the problem?

Comment: remove `columns = ['Klasse', 'Typ', 'Objekt', 'ID']`

Comment: What do you want the `columns` to do? Append does not support that.

Comment: columns should probably go in the DataFrame constructor not in `list.append`

Answer (score 0):

You're appending to a list, the only argument `append` takes the element to append to the list.

```py
l = []
for element in elements:
    l.append(element)
```

See the documentation on [mutable sequence types (including `list`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).